Thriller revenge movie
I am looking for the name of a movie. If anyone can help I would be grateful. I saw it on tv on either BBC or its player. It was Spanish/Portuguese. 
The plot was something like this:

Some guy gets accused of murdering his wife and weird things happen while he's with the police trying to prove that he is innocent. 
He also has a younger girlfriend. 
As the story develops it looks like he has been framed by the police guy because years back, the guy had killed his wife in a hit and run. 
The younger girlfriend turns out to be the police guy's daughter. 
The guy ends up being killed by the policeman.

What is the name of this movie? 

sounds similar to live flesh but it's slightly different

It's El cuerpo - The Body (2012).
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1937149/
Detective Jaime Peña (José Coronado) investigating the apparent theft of a corpse. Adding to the enigma is the fact it was stolen before an autopsy could be carried out, and its previous occupier Mayka (Belén Rueda) died in unusually sudden circumstances. As Jamie continues his investigation, it becomes increasingly clear to him that Álex (Hugo Silva), Mayka’s former husband, is responsible for the death and disappearance. 
a review: http://thisishorror.co.uk/film-review-body-el-cuerpo-2012 

Could you please explain why or provide a synopsis at least? (The one in IMDb is in Spanish)

Detective Jaime Peña (José Coronado) investigating the apparent theft of a corpse. Adding to the enigma is the fact it was stolen before an autopsy could be carried out, and its previous occupier Mayka (Belén Rueda) died in unusually sudden circumstances. As Jamie continues his investigation, it becomes increasingly clear to him that Álex (Hugo Silva), Mayka’s former husband, is responsible for the death and disappearance. http://www.thisishorror.co.uk/film-review-body-el-cuerpo-2012/

Sorry... is it fair to give "-1" to the correct answer (nothing to describe, just watch the movie and you'll see everything in the question fits it) and give "2" to a rotine question from the moderator, I'm sure Walt asks this question several times every day.

I'm not the downvoter, but if you saw the film and think it fits, please describe first-hand how it fits the question since people might not know it (I sure don't) and the external synopsis in your comment above doesn't sound too similar to the plot detailed in the question.

OK, thanks, the plot is rather complex (can't remember it off top of my head), I can't find detailed description anywhere on the net, I'll try something.

Hi Dima, and welcome. I edited your answer to include the description from your comment above.

@ShizZ. Thanks ShizZ., that's very kind of you, but since the topic starter lost interest (she's not seen on the site after the question) I'm not sure if it will help anybody, except me because now I have more "reputation".)
